# mule move pdf ,ppt file .mulerequesteor

Tags: mule, mule-studio

```
<mulerequester:request config-ref="Mule_Requester1" resource="file:///#[flowVars.filename]" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
 <object-to-byte-array-transformer/>
 <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\OUTPUT"  responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Filewrite" outputPattern="#[flowVars.inpfilename]"/>
```

Please note below points

the above flow will create files (pdf,ppt,image ) with corrupted format in C:\OUTPUT folder

**

### Is there any other way to move pdf ,ppt file to other folder using by muletrequester only. because it is my requiremnet

**. the file i want to move like pdf,ppt,image etc.

anyone suggest solution for that

Answer (score 0):

There might be a **bug** in **mule requester module** which is causing this issue, and I have already reported a **Jira** for this issue

An **alternative solution** can be :-
Create a separate flow and define a file inbound endpoint which will pick up the files and dispatch to a file outbound endpoint in that flow .. Now, make that initial state of the **flow="stopped"** and, at the end of that flow after file outbound use the following expression :-

```
<scripting:component>
    <scripting:script engine="groovy">
        muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('targetFlow').stop()
    </scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
```

Now this will stop the flow after the file has been dispatched to outbound location

Now call this flow from your main flow with flow-ref
Since the initial state of this flow is stopped so this flow will only activate when you call this flow using flow-ref from your main flow and will again deactivate when you use scripting component at the end after file outbound endpoint which I shown you above

**UPDATED**
Please try the following example with your requirement

```
    <flow name="mainflow" doc:name="mainflow">
<!-- your previous code -->
    <foreach collection="#[payload]" doc:name="For Each">
      <flow-ref name="fileFlow" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
     </foreach>
    </flow>

    <flow name="fileFlow" doc:name="fileFlow" initialState="stopped">
    <!--Here your file inbound with use sessionVar as path instead of flowVars-->
    <!-- file outbound and path as sessionVar --> 
    <scripting:component>
        <scripting:script engine="groovy">
            muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('fileFlow').start()
        </scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
    </flow>
```

Comment: <foreach collection="#[payload]" doc:name="For Each">
 <mulerequester:request config-ref="Mule_Requester1" resource="file:///#[flowVars.filename]" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
 <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\OUTPUT"  responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Filewrite"  outputPattern="#[flowVars.name]]"/>
 </foreach>                                                                                                                   Here where i added the above script. my requirement is like inside for each loop dynamically move files to output folder

Comment: Now, instead of Mule requester here use flow-ref  to call the flow with File inbound as I mentioned in my answer, follow the steps ... also remove file outbound from here and put it in the other flow.....and one more thing ... use sessionVars instead of flowVars now, since you will be defining file inbound in another flow

Comment: Check my updated answer and try this with your requirement :)